# Getting 500 error for Volley PUT request android

Tags: android, android-volley

**CustomRequest.java**

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;
    private Map<String, String> headers;

    public CustomRequest(String url,
                         Map<String, String> params,
                         Map<String, String> headers,
                         Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener,
                         ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    public CustomRequest(int method,
                         String url,
                         Map<String, String> params,
                         Map<String, String> headers,
                         Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener,
                         ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
```

**I am using request like this in my class**:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Iterator it = params.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            Log.d(context.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "params - " + pairs.getKey() + ", " + pairs.getValue());
        }

        String url = AppConstants.SERVER_URL  + mApi + "/" + mType+ "/" +mWord.getID();

        Log.d("FinalUrl:->", url);

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ActDrawAreaTwo.this);
        CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.PUT,
                                                        url,
                                                        params,
                                                        headers,
                                                        this.createRequestSuccessListener(),
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueueHelper.addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest, "");
```

---

**I am getting error**:

```
11-22 10:28:01.605 17921-18491/com.app.admin E/Volley: [3516] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500
```

**Its a put request, its working in postman**

[image]

Comment: Most likely the request is not being sent correctly. Are you sure the params are there?

Comment: It looks like you're not setting any `params` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your Postman screenshot, I suggest you use the following sample code:

```
        String url = "http://...";
        JSONObject jsonBody;
        try {
            jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("ID", 1);
            jsonBody.put("Name", "Word1");
            jsonBody.put("ArabicName", "Arabic Word1");
            // other key-value pairs...

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // do something
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // do something
                }
            });

            queue.add(request);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope this helps!